# Barrel adjuster for sram gx rear derailleur?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear, sram, shifting

I'm doing a bit of an unorthodox build right now. It's a specialized awol using a sram gx 1x11 drivetrain, but, because I'm running trp hylex discs, I've opted to use a sram s500 bar end shifter. An unforeseen issue is that the gx system places the barrel adjuster on the mtb shifters and omits them from the derailleur, while the road oriented Rival system omits the adjuster from the shifter and places it on the derailleur. Long story short, given my setup, I've got no barrel adjusters and getting the correct cable tension is killing me!! Is there a way to install an "after market" solution. It should be noted that the awol is setup for full length cable housing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need any inline barrel adjuster.
 [image: inline barrel adjuster]

Comment: Perfect. Didn't know that existed. Thanks Nathan!